# react-dropdown-input Module not found: Error

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm trying to use the `react-dropdown-input` library in my react project.
(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropdown-input)
I used `npm i react-dropdown-input` and it installed.
But when I run my project, I get this errors:

> ERROR in ./~/react-dropdown-input/index.js
>  Module not found: Error:
>  Can't resolve 'react/addons' in 'path\node_modules\react-dropdown-input'

And this one too

> ERROR in ./~/react-dropdown-input/index.js 
>   Module not found: Error:
>  Can't resolve 'react/lib/joinClasses' in 'path\node_modules\react-dropdown-input'

I also tried to run this command: `npm install @types/react-dropdown-input` but that library doesn't exists.
This is my import line:

```
import DropdownInput from "react-dropdown-input";
```

In my code it also says this:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-dropdown-input'.
```

Does anyone knows why this is happening and how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested on npm@6.4.1, node@10.13.0. It fails.

I tried cloning it. Looks like library in not maintained. Its last commit was around 5 years back.
You can have a look at [React Autosuggest](https://react-autosuggest.js.org/). Its provides exact features you are looking for.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Then It says: Module '"c:/localhost/project/node_modules/@types/react-autosuggest/index"' has no default export.

Comment: How are you trying to import the module in react? Can you share some code please

Comment: control your package-lock.json and package.json

Comment: `import Autosuggest from "react-autosuggest";`

Comment: I ran `npm install @types/react-autosuggest` and `npm install react-autosuggest --save`

Comment: You just need "react-autosuggest".
Here is a code sandbox you can refer.
[React Autosuggest Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/o7x2noqjzq)

Comment: Its installed on my project, but it says: `Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-autosuggest'. 'c:/localhost/www/project/node_modules/react-autosuggest/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

Comment: What build config are you using? We will need more details than this.
Its hard to say whats causing the issue.
Can you share some code related to this?

Comment: Its working now, I only want it to work without a state, just an object